# Carbonating pasteurized cider ... experimenters?

Tags: carbonation

I've made a few batches of hard cider but now wanting to do something different.

When I was a kid the neighbors gave us fresh pressed apple cider and if we didn't drink it right away it would turn hard and become carbonated.

I have purchased Cider that is pasteurized, dark and cloudy, no additives. I don't  want to actually create alcohol but I want it to be sweet and fizzy. If this is possible.

Could I just add a slight bit of yeast and cap it? Maybe a pinch? Not enough to cause it to blow.

I really appreciate any info, yay or nay

Answer (score 1):

Adding yeast to produce gas will also produce alcohol.

Adding a pinch of yeast is not the solution since yeast cells will reproduce themselves until all the sugar is converted to alcohol and CO2 (unless you pasteurize again to kill the yeast).

Force carbonation seems to be what you need, but it will cost you to pruchase the equipment.  A sodastream could work, but usually it doesn't work well with beer because of the foam, cider could be fine but I am not sure.

-- *Edit* --
Non fermentable sugars can be added to get that sweetness feel as well.

Comment: Thanks Phillipe. I was hoping adding just a little yeast and capping it tight would produce some fizz. Oh yes the soda streams are expensive and I have no idea how to refill the CO2. Thanks again.

Comment: You can do this to get the fizz, but the yeast will not stop working until your cider is completely dry.  Unless you add sugar back when you pour it into a glass.

Comment: You can ferment it dry and add some non fermentable sugars to keep some sweetness as well.